# Missing template application/refreshonline ERROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am writing a method in application controller class

```
ApplicationController < ActionController::Base 
  protect_from_forgery

  def refreshonline 
  end

end
```

and put view in app/views/layout/refreshonline.html.erb this file only contain simple html

but when I run this method it give me error `Missing template application/refreshonline with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "D:/bitnami/test/projects/online/app/views"`

so i am puting my html file in right location or need to put somewhere else ??

Answer (score 0):

If you move refreshonline.html.erb up one level into the views folder this will work.

It would be better practice for you to include a new controller for the resource and move the view into a folder of the same name ([see here for reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html)).